# Spring application overwrite data sometimes when have many session in small amount of time

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, wildfly, overwrite

I have  application build by spring MVC on Wildfly
this App works find most of time - it is reservation App
in race condition for 5 min
I found replacement of data what does that mean
it means client choose product A and he has print out from his screen
but when Administrator check it find it product B

- I have made stress test on my develop  machine (JDK 8) nothing happened.  -- MY production machine (JDK 11)
- what could be the issue? any body can help

Comment: You expect us to help you find a solution for which we have no code, no configuration nor tests? That is not going to happen as we don't know what is going on. Please provide the necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

thank you
this issue was happened with me

if you are using web farm then do not use "in proc" session instead use state server

you can find it [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f958cb48-1553-467b-a190-ec09b309b089/session-values-getting-overwritten-when-two-users-accessing-the-same-page-from-differnt-computer?forum=aspstatemanagement)